# Different variable value in Vue.js + Webpack in dev server vs build

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I'm working on a Vue.js project which is running Webpack in local development & builds static files for deployment.

There is a variable `apiDomain` which needs to change from:

`http://localhost.api/` - in local development

to

`https://api.example.com/` - in the static build files

I've been trying to get my head around environmental variables but I'm not sure how they work in Webpack vs Vue.js.

What is the correct way to setup a Vue.js variable so it's different between local development & the static build files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt this idea for your needs:

```
import axios from "axios";

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

console.log(`we are on [${env}] environment`);

const addr = {
  production: "https://rosetta-beer-store.io",
  development: "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
};

const api = axios.create({
  headers: {"x-api-key": "my-api-key", "x-secret-key": ""},
  baseURL: addr[env],
});

export const beerservice = {
  list: params => api.get("/beer/list", {params}),
  find: id => api.get(`/beer/${id}`),
};

export const mediaservice = {
  url: id => (id ? `${addr[env]}/media/${id}` : `${addr[env]}/icon.svg`),
};
```

By using the process.env.NODE_ENV (available on development and build time) you can not only to set the correct profile for the app services endpoints but also manage any tweak you need on your build scripts:

```
const path = require("path");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "html-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  entry: "./src/main.jsx",
  output: {
    filename: "build.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  devtool:
    process.env.NODE_ENV == "development" ? "inline-source-map" : undefined,
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist",
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./index.html"
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

You can see more examples on [this github project](https://github.com/sombriks/rosetta-beer-store), but the general idea is to take advantage of node at the build time